# How to override bootstrap container on the right?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a border bottom that is overrule the container width to the right. So I have two colomns of six `col-md-6`. The right one has an article as a child. That article has a border-bottom of one px. That should reach the window viewports right. See image bellow:

[image]

As you can see, the right vertical line wil show the container end. There should stop the content and let text for example position on a new line. But the border should overrule that so it will reach the viewport right.

Oh and I make use of bootstrap grid if that was not clear!

Code in progress:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaewLB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borders can't extend beyond their element.

BUT you can use a pseudo-element instead; like so.

```
.page header,
.page article {
  padding: 60px 30px;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2; */
  position: relative; /* positioning context */
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* prevent scrollbars */
}
.page header::after,
.page article::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #c2c2c2;
  width: 100vw; /* or some other large px/em value */
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pjLEaj)

Comment: Thank you. This was what I would like to have!